# Sorting alphabetically without sort method

Tags: java, methods, sorting

Is their another way to sort a list of names that the user inputs individually in the output box other than the "Collections.Sort(list) method?

```
import java.util.*;

public class UserInput 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    String strin = stdin.next();
    if (isNumeric(strin)) {
        System.out.println("Please add a non numeric value");
    } else {
        list.add(strin);
    }

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
    System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");

} while (stdin.next().startsWith("y"));

System.out.println("List is " + list);
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
}
}
```

Comment: You could manually implement any number of string sorting algorithms - but why don't you want to use the default library implementation? If you don't want to wastefully re-sort the entire collection with each entry, use a collection that sorts on insertion, such as the TreeSet ->http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from implementing any sort algorithm you want.  The traditional bubble sort is the first thing that comes to mind...

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? use Collections.sort with your own Comparator if you want to do a custom sort

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework.

Comment: You could use the `String1.compareTo(String2);` method, look it up here: [String#CompareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

Comment: The main reason is because the professor wants us to find a different way.

Comment: Here's a different way, although perhaps not recommended: http://pastebin.com/iJ4DZYu7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to store the names. You can also provide it with a `Comparator` if you need to customize the sort ordering.

**Edit**

As @jahroy commented, it will work because the elements (in a `TreeSet`) are sorted when they are inserted, so there's no need to perform any sort afterwards.

Comment: @jahroy: You should be more precise. What you say only holds true for `TreeSet`, not any `Set`.

Comment: @jahroy rubbish. Sets store and iterate in any order they like. Exceptions to this are SortedSets (eg TreeSer), which iterate in sorted order, and the special LinkedHashSet, which iterates in inserted order.

Comment: @Bohemian - Very true.  I briefly confused the concept of _sorted_ collections with _unique_ collections.  All I was trying to do was get NilsH to add that the order (of a TreeSet) will be maintained upon insertion (which was not originally mentioned).  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Can you provide some sort of an example of how I could implement the "TreeSet" into my code? I looked at the example and am a bit confused

Comment: @user2213611 - A _TreeSet_ maintains the order of its elements internally, so all you have to do is create a new _TreeSet_ and start adding elements to it.  They will automatically be sorted as they are inserted.  There's nothing more to it.  Here's [a link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which will tell you all about it.  You can create a TreeSet using its default constructor.  You can add elements to it by using the _add()_ method.